# How do we determine as to how long we should sum an asymptotic series of a function to get the answer correct up to a particular precision?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, asymptotics

As an example, consider the asymptotic expansion for [polygamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function#Asymptotic_expansion)  . What should be the min value of 'k' in the equation to get the answer correct upto a particular precision, say pth. Is there a relation between p and k. Or is it simple trial and error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accuracy of an asymptotic series depends on the series and its argument.
Usually, the accuracy increases up to a point as more terms are taken.
After this point, the accuracy decreases and the series eventually diverges.

A reasonable tactic is to add terms as long as they decrease in value
and stop when they start increasing.